# Programmatically run a container on Google container engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-kubernetes-engine

I want to run a container from app engine code. The Google doc [link](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/quickstart) gives command line options to do this. Is there a way of doing this programmatically?

Edit: I enabled verbose logs on the command given in the above link, to run a container from gcloud shell, to see the REST API that it accesses.

```
kubectl run hello-node --image=gcr.io/google-samples/node-hello:1.0 --port=8080
```

Then I obtained the IP and credentials (username and password) of the master node from the cloud console and used it to access the REST API with basic authentication from ARC. But I get a 403 response with the following error

```
The access to the URL 35.188.149.76 is restricted because the validation of the certificate failed
```

Is this the correct way of programmatically accessing the container engine?

Comment: Please mention what you have tried so far and add more details to the question. Otherwise chances are your question will be downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

You can read API reference for Kubernetes here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/ and use its Go or Python (or other) clients to program against the Kubernetes API.